# Issue with LoggingFeature not logging the complete response body

Tags: java, kotlin, logging, jersey, dropwizard

I'm currently working building an endpoint that will make a couple of requests to an external API. In this endpoint I'm logging all of the request bodies to the terminal. But I'm having an issue where jerseys **LoggingFeature** doesn't log the complete response body for a request that is done. The log gets cut in the middle of the body. I've tried messing around with the logger level, verbosity but that did nothing. I tried changing **maxEntitySize** to be a large value but that doesn't change anything either, I'm not really sure what the issue is and why it won't log the complete response body. I've also tried logging to a file instead of the terminal but unfortunately I got the same result.

Here's what the log looks like (as it's proprietary software I had to change some information)

```
INFO  [2022-10-06 13:54:04,261] se.bla.bla.bla.clients.BlaClientImpl: 1 * Sending client request on thread dw-18 - GET /api/bla/log/98014384
1 > GET https://url.com/2574339575
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Authorization: Bearer tokenstuff

INFO  [2022-10-06 13:54:04,475] se.bla.bla.bla.clients.BlaClientImpl: 1 * Client response received on thread dw-18 - GET /api/bla/log/98014384
1 < 200
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
1 < Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2022 13:54:04 GMT
1 < Etag: Yee
1 < Server-Response-Time: 169.44395400000002
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Vary: Origin
1 < X-Request-Id: Woo
1 < X-Runtime: 0.169337
{example1: "2134123123",example2: "2134123123",example3: "2134123123",example4: "2134123123",example5: "2134123123",example6: "2134123123",example7: "2134123123",example8: "2134123123",example9: "2134123123",example10: "2134123123",example11: "2134123123",example12: "2134123123",example13: "2134123123",example14: "2134123123",example15: "2134123123",example16: "2134123123",example17: "2134123123",example18: "21341
```

And I've registered the logger like so.

```
        val restlog = getLogger(BlaClientImpl::class.java.name)
        restlog.addHandler(FileHandler("rest.log", 83886080, 1))
        val requestBuilder =
            client
                .register(
                    LoggingFeature(
                        restlog,
                        Level.INFO,
                        LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,
                        83886080
                    )
                )
```

I'm quite new to the Kotlin/Java world so maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: You can try to set [this property](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.35/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#LOGGING_FEATURE_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_CLIENT). I don't know if it will make a difference or not if the maxEntitySize argument didn't work

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Hey thanks for you comment. The issue was a settings with Dropwizard/Jersey, apparently I had to set gzipEnabled = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a settings with Dropwizard/Jersey. Apparently I had to set gzipEnabled = true